# How to make css grid with 3 columns with square grid items fit into responsive screen without specifying height and width

Tags: css, angular, responsive-design, css-grid

I am trying to figure out the CSS to create a dynamic grid with 3 columns and the grid items are square. And it should adjust to the height and width whenever changed to the responsive view.
I am using angular 15.

This code works fine for desktop view but when I switch to smaller screen like small mobiles they don't adjust to the screen, rather it adds scroll at the bottom of the page.

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(175px, 175px))!important;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(175px, 1fr))!important;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-item {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: If you want it to be responsive better to use percentage  in your grid-template-columns and rows

Comment: Also Why do you set minmax(175px, 175px) this will keep colum width 175px always

Comment: So something like - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yLraNEJ